# Kotlin error Cannot weaken access privilege 'public' for 'value' in 'valueformelement'

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to implement some code from Java to Kotlin while learning and frankly I don't know how to fix that error.Am a noob and just began Kotlin so please any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
``class ElementPosPayment : FormElement, ValueFormElement, 
      ReadyFormElement, ApiDataView, View.OnClickListener {

//Error occurs here on both value and activity variables declarations
private var value: String? = null 
private var activity: BaseActivity? = null 




//The interface class for ValueFormElement is
interface ValueFormElement : BaseElement {

var value: Pair<Boolean, Hashtable<String, String>>
var name: String
fun setValue(value: String)

}
```

Comment: I am not getting any error when using your kotlin code. Maybe there is some code missing?

Answer (score 1):

When you create an interface, the methods and properties are always public. When you implement that interface, you have to continue to expose the methods and properties as public, otherwise you'd be breaking the interface contract.

```
class ElementPosPayment : FormElement, ValueFormElement, 
  ReadyFormElement, ApiDataView, View.OnClickListener {
    override var value: String? = null 
    override var activity: BaseActivity? = null 
 }
```